What's this chord, and what's its function in Schubert's Waltz D145 Op18 n°4?
In this waltz of Schubert's how can we analyse the first chord of the second system: A♯ E F A♮ C♯ E?

This is my current analysis:

My observations are :

This chord has 2 forced movements:

A-F are resolving to G♯ of the next G♯m chord (as would normally an augmented sixth chord) (rose)
And the A♯ is resolving to B as a kind of vii°/V in E (orange)


At this point of the piece, the tonality is E.


How would you analyse this passage ?

There is a similar chord/movement at measure 5/6, but the absence of a A♮ next to the A♯, and the G♮ being labelled G♮ and not F, makes it clearer to understand.

Here clearly A# is played in the top voice, not A https://youtu.be/_wcHpxIaev4?feature=shared&t=182

Classical harmony is not my wheelhouse but it is basically enharmonically an A#dim7 with an added maj7. It ‘s a pretty commonly used chord in jazz and contemporary music. If you think of it as an inversion of a Fx it is a viio of G#m.

There is a misprint in the score1 — a sharp is missing from the right-hand A. The chord is Fxo7, the vii chord of G# minor, to which it resolves in the next measure.
Here is a correct version of the score:

(Image source: IMSLP, Franz Schubert's Werke, Serie XII, No.2)

1. The error comes from the first edition, of which the question's edition appears to be a reproduction.


As with many of these things all editions are base on the first edition, as the autograph is lost.

If we interpret the chord as a dominant resolving to the following chord (which is what it sounds to me), that would be D#7b9, with the root omitted, and with added b5 coexisting with with natural 5.
In some recordings I was able to find quickly, instead of the A note in the melody, A# is played:

Michael Endres 


Vladimir Ashkenazy 



though A would sound interesting too, extra dissonant.

Why not just an inversion of Fxo7? That’s also a dominant chord.

@JohnBelzaguy yeah, that works too. I somehow tend to think of diminished chords in this context as of dominants without root. The functional interpretation is more clear too me. Moreover it is easier to understand potential function of the A note in this chord.

Actually the A muddies things even further IMO, the A  or #11 wasn’t really a thing back then. Neither were rootless dominant chords.

The A is most likely an engraving error. The Autograph for this part is lost, so the only source for all edition is the first edition. Some later editions do correct the A to an A♯, but these are all based on the first edition.
